# Symfony3 Type-hint Created Services

Tags: symfony-3.3

How do I configure my created services to be able to be type-hinted? I have looked in all the service container docs, and anything to do with symfony docs and nothing I am trying works...

Added this to services.yml

```
    Tester:    
         class: AppBundle\Services\Tester
         public: true
```

Added this to my class

```
    use AppBundle\Services\Tester;
```

Tried to type-hint "Tester $test" and get errors. Doing something wrong...

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: When I try to add mailer for instance, it tells me the class does not exist....

Comment: Actually, here is the exact output...the code is a bit different but error is the same...

Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Services\Tester::onTest() must be an instance of SwiftMailer, none given, called in /home/xXxX/symfony-test-sites/xXxX/src/AppBundle/Controller/TestLoggerController.php on line 30

Comment: It says it right there `onTest` needs 1 arg of `SwiftMailer` - you're not passing the arg it needs

Comment: Ive figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, `Tester` is a service name, as opposed to a classname that is a service.

If you have a the class in that location, and you also want it to be public (to use in a `$container->get('\AppBundle\Services\Tester')` or `->get(Tester::class)`, you can define it like this.

```
AppBundle\Services\Tester:
    public: true
```

If you are only going to be using it as a type-hint, you don't need the `public:true`, and if the class is being imported elsewhere (probably further up the same file), you may not even need the lines at all unless it has parameters that can't themselves be autowired.

If you only need it to be `get()`-able in a test environment, it can be worth just creating a service alias, only for services_tesy.yml:

```
# available as ->get('test_Tester') in a test
test_Tester:
    class: AppBundle\Services\Tester:
    public: true
```

Comment: I see what you are talking about. I honestly had forgotten about it. I moved past it for the moment. I do understand better now and have found a way to work it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed. I was having problems with the yaml editor in Eclipse. It was making a mess of tabs and was continually giving me problems in other areas too. I ended up installing YEdit and everything seemed to work.